# Is there any easier/more efficient way to perform this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a table that shows relations between records in a sort of "parent to child" fashion. An [ID] field identifies a record and a [PARENT] field identifies that record's parent by [ID]. This creates a tree structure for the top-most parent. See the below table as an example:

```
[ID]     [PARENT]     [QUANTITY]
123      123          1
456      123          2
789      123          1
321      456          1
654      321          2
987      321          4
```

Notice how record with [ID] = '123' is the top-most record in this "tree". I need to query this table to select all tree nodes (complete records) under the top-most record, for example all of the records beneath [ID] = '123' in the tree (all records in the above sample table). Currently I am using a stored procedure to loop grabbing the children of the record with [ID] = '123', then that records children, etc. I know there must be an easier query (not a stored proc) that could dynamically adapt to this situation I just am not sure how that might work without looping to ensure all children are received. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a hierichal query and in SQL server is accomplished using the syntax XML_Path Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256900/query-to-get-xml-output-for-hierarchical-data-using-for-xml-path-in-sql-server

Comment: Search for `recursive parent child sql query` and you should get a bunch of hits.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I guess knowing what to search makes it incredibly easy. Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "WITH" Common table expression - highly recommended on Hierarichal query.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)